# Pixel Overlapping after Pre-processing in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am a student, currently doing my thesis work using Google Earth Engine.

I'm trying to classify land cover using Landsat 5 images for the whole country, 'Bangladesh'. For this, as an initial step, I need to get a good quality image composite after doing a several correction and filtering. I did those (please find those in the code link below) but the problem is I'm getting the image pixels' edge overlapped on each other. It looks like:

[image]

I think, it'll be a big problem if I use it for my further processing. I'll use it for extracting NDVI and some other indices and finally, will make a composite index to extract different types of land cover. In fact, you can suggest me other codes that can filter images(cloud cover, date, boundary) for the whole country (Bangladesh) altogether into a composite and I'll be able to conduct image calculation (NDVI...etc) among the bands from the composite.

Another thing is that could you recommend me which reducer or method should I use to eliminate this type of problem looks like below (I want Uniformity).

[image]

Could you see my codes and check that if any modification is required?

```
var studyArea = Bangladesh;

////////////////////////////////////////
// Composite time period
// startYear: First year to include imagery from
var startYear = 1989

// endYear: Last year to include imagery from
var endYear = 1992

// startJulian: Starting Julian Date- Supports wrapping for tropics and 
//     southern hemisphere
var startJulian = 305;

// endJulian: Ending Julian date- Supports wrapping for tropics and 
//     southern hemisphere.
var endJulian = 90;     

////////////////////////////////////////
// Composite parameters
// cloudThresh: If using the cloudScoreTDOMShift method-Threshold for cloud 
//     masking (lower number masks more clouds.  Between 10 and 30 generally 
//     works best)
var cloudThresh = 20; 

// dilatePixels: Number of pixels to buffer clouds and cloud 
//     shadows by (1 or 2 generally is sufficient)
var dilatePixels = 2;    

// cloudHeights: Height of clouds to use to project cloud shadows
var cloudHeights = ee.List.sequence(200,5000,500);

// zScoreThresh: Threshold for cloud shadow masking- lower number masks out 
// less.  Between -0.8 and -1.2 generally works well
var zScoreThresh = -0.8;    

// shadowSumThresh: Sum of IR bands to include as shadows within TDOM and the 
// shadow shift method (lower number masks out less)
var shadowSumThresh = 0.35;    

////////////////////////////////////////
// Export parameters
// Give the study area a descriptive name. This name is used for output 
// composites file names.
var exportName = 'Bangladesh'; 

// EPSG number for output projection. 32645 = WGS84/UTM Zone 45N. 
// For more info- http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/  
var crs = 'EPSG:32645'; 


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Functions
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Function for acquiring Landsat TOA image collection
function getImageCollection(studyArea,startDate,endDate,startJulian,endJulian){
  var ls;var l5TOAs;var out;

  var sensorBandDictLandsatTOA =ee.Dictionary({L5 : ee.List([0,1,2,3,4,5,6])});
  var bandNamesLandsatTOA = ee.List(['blue','green','red','nir','swir1','temp',
      'swir2']);


  l5TOAs = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT5_L1T_TOA')
      .filterDate(startDate,endDate)
      .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(startJulian,endJulian))
      .filterBounds(studyArea)
      .select(sensorBandDictLandsatTOA.get('L5'),bandNamesLandsatTOA);


  ls = ee.ImageCollection(l5TOAs);
  out = ls;
  return out;
}


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// A helper to apply an expression and linearly rescale the output.
// Used in the landsatCloudScore function below.
var rescale = function(img, exp, thresholds) {
  return img.expression(exp, {img: img})
      .subtract(thresholds[0]).divide(thresholds[1] - thresholds[0]);
};

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Compute a cloud score and adds a band that represents the cloud mask.  
// This expects the input image to have the common band names: 
// ["red", "blue", etc], so it can work across sensors.
function landsatCloudScore(img) {
  // Compute several indicators of cloudiness and take the minimum of them.
  var score = ee.Image(1.0);
  // Clouds are reasonably bright in the blue band.
  score = score.min(rescale(img, 'img.blue', [0.1, 0.3]));

  // Clouds are reasonably bright in all visible bands.
  score = score.min(rescale(img, 'img.red + img.green + img.blue', [0.2, 0.8]));

  // Clouds are reasonably bright in all infrared bands.
  score = score.min(
      rescale(img, 'img.nir + img.swir1 + img.swir2', [0.3, 0.8]));

  // Clouds are reasonably cool in temperature.
  score = score.where(img.select(['temp']).mask(),score.min(rescale(img,
      'img.temp', [300, 290])));

  // However, clouds are not snow.
  var ndsi = img.normalizedDifference(['green', 'swir1']);
  score =  score.min(rescale(ndsi, 'img', [0.8, 0.6])).multiply(100).byte();
  score = score.lt(cloudThresh).rename('cloudMask');
  img = img.updateMask(img.mask().and(score));
  return img.addBands(score);
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Function for finding dark outliers in time series.
//Original concept written by Carson Stam and adapted by Ian Housman.
//Adds a band that is a mask of pixels that are dark, and dark outliers.
function simpleTDOM2(collection,zScoreThresh,shadowSumThresh,dilatePixels){
  var shadowSumBands = ['nir','swir1'];

  //Get some pixel-wise stats for the time series
  var irStdDev = collection.select(shadowSumBands).reduce(ee.Reducer.stdDev());
  var irMean = collection.select(shadowSumBands).mean();

  //Mask out dark dark outliers
  collection = collection.map(function(img){
    var zScore = img.select(shadowSumBands).subtract(irMean).divide(irStdDev);
    var irSum = img.select(shadowSumBands).reduce(ee.Reducer.sum());
    var TDOMMask = zScore.lt(zScoreThresh).reduce(ee.Reducer.sum()).eq(2)
        .and(irSum.lt(shadowSumThresh)).not();
    TDOMMask = TDOMMask.focal_min(dilatePixels);
    return img.addBands(TDOMMask.rename('TDOMMask'));
  });

  return collection;
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Function for wrapping cloud and shadow masking together.
//Assumes image has cloud mask band called "cloudMask" and a TDOM mask called 
//"TDOMMask".
function cloudProject(img,shadowSumThresh,dilatePixels,cloudHeights){

  //Get the cloud mask
  var cloud = img.select('cloudMask').not();
  cloud = cloud.focal_max(dilatePixels);
  cloud = cloud.updateMask(cloud);

  //Get TDOM mask
  var TDOMMask = img.select(['TDOMMask']).not();

  //Project the shadow finding pixels inside the TDOM mask that are dark and 
  //inside the expected area given the solar geometry
  //Find dark pixels
  var darkPixels = img.select(['nir','swir1','swir2'])
      .reduce(ee.Reducer.sum()).lt(shadowSumThresh);//.gte(1);

  //Get scale of image
  var nominalScale = cloud.projection().nominalScale();

  //Find where cloud shadows should be based on solar geometry
  //Convert to radians
  var meanAzimuth = img.get('SUN_AZIMUTH');
  var meanZenith = img.get('SUN_ELEVATION');
  var azR = ee.Number(meanAzimuth).multiply(Math.PI).divide(180.0)
      .add(ee.Number(0.5).multiply(Math.PI ));
  var zenR = ee.Number(0.5).multiply(Math.PI )
      .subtract(ee.Number(meanZenith).multiply(Math.PI).divide(180.0));

  //Find the shadows
  var shadows = cloudHeights.map(function(cloudHeight){
    cloudHeight = ee.Number(cloudHeight);
    var shadowCastedDistance = zenR.tan()
        .multiply(cloudHeight);//Distance shadow is cast
    var x = azR.cos().multiply(shadowCastedDistance)
        .divide(nominalScale).round();//X distance of shadow
    var y = azR.sin().multiply(shadowCastedDistance)
        .divide(nominalScale).round();//Y distance of shadow
    return cloud.changeProj(cloud.projection(), cloud.projection()
        .translate(x, y));
  });

  var shadow = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(shadows).max();

  //Create shadow mask
  shadow = shadow.updateMask(shadow.mask().and(cloud.mask().not()));
  shadow = shadow.focal_max(dilatePixels);
  shadow = shadow.updateMask(shadow.mask().and(darkPixels).and(TDOMMask));

  //Combine the cloud and shadow masks
  var combinedMask = cloud.mask().or(shadow.mask()).eq(0);

  //Update the image's mask and return the image
  img = img.updateMask(img.mask().and(combinedMask));
  img = img.addBands(combinedMask.rename(['cloudShadowMask']));
  return img;
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Function to calculate NDVI
function ndvi_function(input) {
  var img = input.select("nir", "red").normalizedDifference();
  return img.addBands(input.metadata("system:time_start"));
}

// vizParams: Options for map visualization
var vizParams = {'min': 0.05,'max': 0.5, 'bands':'swir1,nir,red', 
    'gamma':1.6};
var vizParamsRescale = {'min': 500,'max': 5000, 'bands':'swir1,nir,red', 
    'gamma':1.6};

Map.addLayer(studyArea, null, "Study Area",false);
Map.centerObject(geometry, 16);

// Prepare dates
if(startJulian > endJulian){endJulian = endJulian + 365}
var startDate = ee.Date.fromYMD(startYear,1,1).advance(startJulian,'day');
var endDate = ee.Date.fromYMD(endYear,1,1).advance(endJulian,'day');
print('Start and end dates:',startDate,endDate);

// Get Landsat 5 Image Collections
var ls = getImageCollection(studyArea, startDate, endDate, startJulian, endJulian);
Map.addLayer(ls.median().clip(studyArea), vizParams,
  'Landsat before masking composite', false);

// Compute a cloud score and mask clouds
ls = ls.map(landsatCloudScore);

// Find and mask out dark outliers
ls = simpleTDOM2(ls,zScoreThresh,shadowSumThresh,dilatePixels);

// Run cloud project to get the final cloud and shadow masked image collection
ls = ls.map(function(img){return cloudProject(img,shadowSumThresh,dilatePixels,
    cloudHeights)});

// Run reducer on image collection 
var composite = ls.median();

// Get descriptive name.
var fullName = exportName+'_'+startYear.toString()+'_' +endYear.toString()+'_'+startJulian.toString()+'_'+endJulian.toString()+'_Composite';

//Set up the export image.
var finalComposite = composite.select(
  ['blue','green','red','nir','swir1','swir2']
  ).multiply(10000).int16().clip(studyArea);

// Add the final image to display.
Map.addLayer(finalComposite.clip(studyArea), vizParamsRescale, 
  fullName, true);
```

Note: My study area is Bangladesh which is a temperate coastal region on WGS 45N.

Here is my codes in GEE code editor: 
https://code.earthengine.google.com/b1a9ad65ebbbfd176f5abb1d691c1f35

Comment: We're a little different from other sites. We're a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.

Comment: I've corrected as per your comments. Thanks!